# The annotion of row in ComplexHeatmap was not fully displayed

Tags: r, complexheatmap

I am using ComplexHeatmap to show the expression of genes across several cells. Here is a toy example where each row represents a gene.

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 14; nr3 = 16; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 2; nc2 = 2; nc3 = 2; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
colnames(mat) = paste0("col", seq_len(nc))
rownames(mat) = c("MS4A1","BANK1" ,"CD79A","IL7R", "CD40LG","CD8A", "CD8B", "PECAM1","TM4SF1","STC1", 
                  "LUM","COL1A1","COL1A2","KRT18" ,"KRT19","EPCAM","TPSAB1","KIT","C1QB", "LYZ","AIF1", 
                  "GNLY", "KLRD1","CSF3R","FCGR3B","MZB1","IGLL5","SSR4", "RRM2", "HMGN2","CTLA4","FOXP3","TCL1A","IRF7")


col_fun = colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("green", "white", "red"))

ht_opt(heatmap_column_names_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial"), 
       heatmap_row_names_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial",fontface = "italic",fontsize = 11), 
       heatmap_column_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial"),
       heatmap_row_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial"),
       legend_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial"),
       legend_labels_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Arial"))

ht = Heatmap(mat, 
             # Remove name from fill legend
             name = "Expression",
             # Keep original row/col order
             row_order = rownames(mat), column_order = colnames(mat),
             rect_gp = gpar(col = "#7d7b7d", lwd = 1),
             column_gap = unit(1.5, "mm"),
             row_gap = unit(1.5, "mm"),
             col = col_fun,
             heatmap_legend_param = list(color_bar = "continuous", legend_direction = "horizontal",
                                         at = c( -1, 0, 1, 2, 3),legend_width = unit(5, "cm"), 
                                         title_position = "lefttop"),
             show_row_names = TRUE, show_column_names = TRUE,
             show_row_dend = FALSE, show_column_dend = FALSE,
             row_title = NULL)
draw(ht, heatmap_legend_side = "bottom")
```

[image]

As you can see, some rownames (gene names) are not fully displayed, e.g, FCGR3B (row 25), PECAM1 (row 8). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `padding` argument in the `draw` function

in your case  10 mm is quite good

```
draw(ht, heatmap_legend_side = "bottom",padding = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 10), "mm"))
```

for more detail see here [Jokergoo CHM book](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-list-of-heatmaps.html#manually-increase-space-around-the-plot)

[image: your_HM]